# Javascript Syntax Error - if/else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax

this is my first question so apologies if my issue is not clearly displayed. I'm getting error messages with the 'else' part of the if/else statement. About half-way down the code I've commented on the right hand side of the line where I'm getting the error. Don't know what's wrong with the syntax.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
 if(choice1 === choice2) 
 return "The result is a tie!";
};
else if(choice1==="rock")  //GETTING ERROR MESSAGE
     if(choice2==="scissors");
         {return "rock wins";
     }
     else {
         return"paper wins";  //GETTING ERROR MESSAGE
     }
}
else if(choice1==="paper") {   //GETTING ERROR MESSAGE
     if(choice2==="rock"); 
     {
    return "paper wins";
     }
     else {
     return "scissors wins";
     }
}
 else if(choice1==="scissors") {
      if(choice2==="paper")
      return "scissors wins";
 }
      else {
     return "rock wins" }
     }
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a { after your first else if

Comment: Console will tell you if anything is wrong with your syntax

Comment: @Mr.Alien "I'm getting error messages" kinda hints at that the OP already knows about the console.

Comment: Vars chose1 and chose2 don't exist in the current context. You have closed the function just the line before the error. Move the ";" at the end.

Comment: @Juhana than he lacks research info about those errors, as far as I know, JavaScript errors are too friendly, compared to PHP ones :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is *littered* with syntax and structural errors.  For example, this:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) 
        return "The result is a tie!";
};
else if(choice1==="rock")
```

You declare a function in a variable, but then follow that declaration with an `else` block.  An `else` block needs to follow an `if` block.  You can't just *begin* a statement with `else`.  That makes no sense syntactically to logically.  Should it be part of the `if` block within that function?  Then why did you close the function?  That's going to break pretty much everything after it.

Or this:

```
if(choice2==="rock"); 
{
    return "paper wins";
}
```

Why is there a semi-colon after the `if` conditional?

I'm willing to bet these curly braces don't line up properly throughout the code either.  You definitely want to indent your code to make it more human-readable so you can follow the structure you're creating.  Semi-colons terminate statements, don't just put them wherever.  And `if`/`else` blocks go in pairs.

Step through the logic you're attempting to express and structure it.  This code makes it *very* unclear what you're even trying to do.

Comment: "You declare a function…" nope, that's a function expression. :-)

Comment: @RobG: Well, perhaps my terminology is off.  It's a function, it's just one that's being stored in a variable instead of expressly declared.  The only difference I know of is hoisting.  But after the statement `compare` is an executable function.